# What could cause these scratches on the rear hatch?

Tags: body, paint-scratches, rear, scratch, hatch

I noticed some weird scratches on a part of a car which is not on the exterior. There are similar scratches on both sides:

[image: Scratch 1]

[image: Scratch 2]

What could have caused this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They look like traces of sealer prior to painting.

Leave them alone as they were there from manufacture and you will cause more damage as you will need to repaint after.